# Why does Cassandra Quarkus extension not use smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra-client to interact with Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

In the below guide we can see its all annotation driven and entity , all the dao classes are generated during compile time.

https://quarkus.io/guides/cassandra#reactive

If you want to execute queries natively like u have a sql and prepare stmt and set values, execute it and then process the resultset , you can make use of QuarkusCqlSession class and add db properties in application.properties , this api gives output of Multi type.

cqlSession.prepare(sql).boundStatementBuilder().set(...).build();
cqlSession.executeReactive(boundstmt);

Q) Why the quarkus/**cassandra-quarkus-client** does not use the **smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra-client** to interact with cassandra db ?

Comment: @geoand Can someone explain this? I am

Comment: Can someone explain this? I am confused too. smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra and quarkus-cassandra-client, which one should i  use? @Clement

Answer (score 1):

Because the Cassandra Quarkus extension is also for users that do not wish to use Mutiny and that want to inject a `QuarkusCqlSession` bean directly, anywhere in their application.

That said, it's probably possible for the Cassandra Quarkus extension to also expose an `io.vertx.cassandra.CassandraClient` bean, if Vert.x and Mutiny are in the classpath. That would be a nice addition to the extension.

Comment: io.vertx.cassandra.CassandraClient is not available with cassandra-quarkus-client , need to explicitly add smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra-client dependency to get this class and we need to define this bean and configure db configuration as per CDI . Also if we use smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra-client over the cassandra-quarkus-client  then we need to define custom health check for the db , with cassandra-quarkus-client it does that for us .  Also my concern is what are all the unknown benefits we will miss if we just use the smallrye-mutiny-vertx-cassandra-client and not the quarkus client.